# Eliminating Duplicate Printers on Print Server 2008 R2

Tags: redirection

I added a print server role to our new 2008 R2 server and started adding printers to it that will be available to Remote Desktop sessions. When I added the Remote Desktop services role, I specified printer redirection, thinking that would be a good thing.

On the PCs where I am testing all this, I added the network printers locally so that they would have the printer available for local use.

When I logon to the 2008 R2 server, I notice that the printers I added are out there twice... once on the 2008 R2 server and an additional time redirected from my PC.

Is there some way to eliminate this duplication w/o eliminating redirection?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have the printers installed on the RDS server, which will become local printers to the users who have a session on the RDS server, and you have the same printers being redirected from the RDS client to their session (their local printers redirected to the RDS session). You only need to have one or the other, not both. Here are two methods to deal with this, although I would recommend option 1.

Uninstall the printers on the RDS server

OR

Disable Printer Redirection for the RDS client